# Action cuando logueas WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito saber cuándo se loguea el usuario para verificar si tiene datos de facturación vacíos. Si no es así, le redirecciono a la página para que los rellene.
El caso es que no me funciona wp_login, no sé porqué.

```
function datos_facturacion_user(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id);

    // Campos de facturación
    $nombre = $meta['billing_first_name'][0];
    $direccion = $meta['billing_address_1'][0];

    // Verificar si están vacíos
    if(empty($nombre) || empty($direccion)){

    }

    echo "<script>alert('" . $nombre . " " . $direccion . "')</script>";
}
add_action('wp_login', 'datos_facturacion_user');
```

Comment: al agregar el action proba ponerle `, 10, 2);` prioridad y que te de los 2 parámetros, luego `function datos_facturacion_user(){` quedaría `function datos_facturacion_user($user_login, $user){` y ahi tendrías que poder acceder al user recién logueado

Comment: No me funciona. En todo caso, los argumentos que recibe la función, ¿de dónde salen?

Comment: te los da el action: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

Comment: Pues no lo sé, sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: pasa que después del login hay una redirección (panel, frontpage, blogindex) el echo se reemplaza

Comment: A ver, lo que quiero hacer (por ejemplo), es que nada más loguearme me salte un `alert`. Lo de la redirección todavía no o he hecho

Comment: hay varias opciones, o reescribis el [`wp_authenticate`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate) o programas una alerta de admin para el panel, o en el header.php chequeas que si es usuario logeado, cumple las condiciones y no recibio alerta (lo podes manejar con cookies), le ponga una.